# Facebook not serve new token: This authorization code has expired

Tags: node.js, facebook, passport.js

I'm using Node.js and Passport.js for autenticate users on my website.
All was perfect but sudenly now, I can't login into the website and the users neither.

This is the code error:

`failed to obtain access token (status: 400 data: {"error":{"message":"This authorization code has expired.","type":"OAuthException","code":100}})`

I've tryed to change the app secret but nothing.

Comment: Are you trying to use the same code twice, or too long after the first step in the auth flow?

Comment: @Igy: I am facing this problem. Since the user has changed the password I cam trying to get a new access token and yes I am trying to use the same code to get a new access token after a long time because the FB wont provide me a new code. What am I supposed to do? :|

Answer (score 1):

The access token has expired. You should exchange the short lived token for a long lived token . It's explained at the following URL;

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#long-via-code

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem working with ruby. This is what worked for me, Hope it helps.

1. Restart your server
2. Enter your project at the root index